# type in browser using python module selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

There is this website my teacher makes us use to improve our typing skills. Our assignment is due next month and I am too lazy and want to make a program using selenium, a python module. Everything is working according to plan accept one thing, how do I type on the browser. You don't type in a text box. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/iyadmajid/Desktop/chromedriver')
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
driver.get('https://www.typing.com/student/login')
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('the_username')
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys('the_password')
driver.find_element_by_class_name('submit-login').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/student/lessons/380/numeric-
keypad']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='button begin-button tooltip-
trigger']").click()
```

This is what the screen looks like after the code finishes executing: [the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksyZ0.png). I tried using send_keys('6') but that doesn't work. Here is what website code looks like: [the website code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0kWS.png). Again, if there is a way to type keys on the browser directly, please let me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, try the [PyAutoGui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) module. It can be installed with pip and can press keys. An example that presses the y key:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.firefox()
driver.get("https://www.typing.com/student/login")
```

select element by id:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("a1")
inputElement.send_keys('1')
```

Now you can simulate hitting ENTER:

```
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or if it is a form you can submit:

```
inputElement.submit()
```